# Capital letter sensitive case in android

Tags: android, mysql

In my MYSQL database saved email is `jiaweitan05@gmail.com`. When I login with all capital case for email like `JIAWEITAN05@GMAIL.COM` it is succesfully login since every letter is correct. But how should I do for capital sensitive case for email input. So that when **JIAWEITAN05@GMAIL.COM** of user input while comparing SQL query with small capital **jiaweitan05@gmail.com**  is not match because of capital case sensitive. Or should I consider of implement this feature?

Comment: use `BINARY` eg `SELECT *  FROM table WHERE BINARY email = 'value'`

Comment: just before trying, is it suitable or not suggested of doing this?

Comment: In android You have SQlite not MySQL. Unless you mean on server side, so it is not android then. In addition, RFC standard says, emails are case-sensitive, most servers ignores it to avoid confusion.

Comment: My apologies, my android device was mean to connect to server, and since the RFC statement, I think I don't need consider this method

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whether the email contains capital letter like this :

```
boolean isUpperCase =false;
for(int i=0;i<string.length;i++)
{
  isUpperCase = Character.isUpperCase("My String".charAt(i));

}

 if(isUpperCase==true)
    {
    // give error to user
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE UPPER(column_name) = UPPER('jiaweitan05@gmail.com')
```

Comment: an error message pop out which is `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax`

Comment: try UCASE instead of UPPER, although I find this weird since UPPER works fine with mine...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `case-insensitive collation`. To c`ause a`case-sensitive`comparison of`nonbinary strings`to be case insensitive, use` COLLATE to name a case-insensitive collation

```
Select * from table
where email = 'JIAWEITAN05@GMAIL.COM' collate utf8_bin
```

You have to change your column name

```
email varchar(size) collate utf8_bin
```

A binary string is case sensitive in comparisons. To compare the string as case insensitive, convert it to a `nonbinary` string and use `COLLATE` to name a case-insensitive collation

Example:

```
mysql>SET @s = BINARY 'aBcD';
mysql> SELECT @s, LOWER(@s), UPPER(@s);

+------+-----------+-----------+
| @s   | LOWER(@s) | UPPER(@s) |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| aBcD | abcd      | ABCD      |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS' this is the php error I get

Comment: try `COLLATE utf8_bin` or `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS` only

Comment: if I use `COLLATE Latin1_ General_CS` the error said `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'Latin1_General_CS' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'` but if I put this `COLLATE utf8_bin` it only works for my password part but not for email ( no error message even I capitalize my email just a blank page without a message `Login Succesfully`

Comment: now I have tried all your ideas, But I think its a better way to do this error handling in my php script~ Since I'm not using SQLite